# AndroidPlot graph disappears on landscape view in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot for displaying dynamic data on a graph in my android App.  The graph is displayed in a fragment, which is a part of a tabbed screen (view pager). The graph needs to be displayed in landscape and portrait mode.

When the graph is displayed on the portrait mode, I can see it properly. However, when the phone is turned into landscape mode, the graph disappears completely. This happens only when the AndroidPlot graph is used in a Fragment. When AndroidPlot graph is used in an activity directly without fragment, the graph is displayed correctly in landscape and portrait mode.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

My layout.xml file is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.monitrahealth.mhsmartmct.TestFragment" android:id="@+id/fragment_test">
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
    android:id="@+id/mplot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    androidplot.renderMode="use_background_thread"
    androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
    androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.visible="false"
    androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_label_font_size"
    androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.visible="false"
    androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="0dp"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="0dp"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="0dp"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="0dp"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
    androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
    />
```

And my Fragment code is as follows:

```
public class TestFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View ecgGraphView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ecggraph, container, false);
    XYPlot dynamicPlot = (XYPlot) ecgGraphView.findViewById(R.id.dynamicXYPlot);

    return ecgGraphView;
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}}
```

Comment: what happens if you start the app in portrait mode instead of landscape mode?

Comment: I can see the graph properly when I start in portrait mode.

Comment: sorry, got my words mixed up - meant landscape instead of portrait. just trying to understand whether the problem is a function of the starting state or if its actually a problem with landscape.

Comment: Nick, I cannot see the graph when I start the app in landscape mode.

Comment: What about when you rotate back to portrait from landscape?  Does it appear again?  I thoroughly re-tested the library with fragments this morning and was unable to replicate your issue.  I did notice that some of your variable names have "ecg" in them, which implies a dynamic plot.  Are you certain you're properly restarting any background threads etc. after the rotate?  Without seeing more of your code I'm afraid that's about all the help I can provide.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out to me nick. I will take a harder look at my code and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Nick, I checked my code, I was using a background thread which was resetting the view on rotate, hence my graph was disappearing. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.